# Who established the current standard demonstration of Euler-Lagrange equation in calculus of variations?

Tags: mathematics, mathematical-physics

Who established the current standard(*) demonstration of Euler-Lagrange equations in calculus of variations, that is, $\displaystyle\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}-\frac{d}{dx}\frac{\partial f}{\partial \dot y} = 0 $?. As far as I know, the closest author could be JACOBI (*On the theory of the Calculus of Variations and of differential equations*, 1837(**). Really, he starts writing the exact equation and after tries to demonstrate it.

So, he starts writing:

> "*Let us consider the simplest case; let the integral is to have a maximum or minimum value be*
> $$\displaystyle\int f(x, y, y') dx,$$
> *where $y'$ is put $\displaystyle\frac{dy}{dx}$. Then we know that $y$ is to be found from the differential equation*
> $$\displaystyle\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}-\frac{d}{dx}\frac{\partial f}{\partial \dot y} = 0$$
> "

Since then, the demonstrations Jacobi made have nothing to do with modern usuals ones, yet cited. I think they are more complex and, actually, I don't understand them at all.

Moreover, why or who put the so called name 'Euler-Lagrange' to the equation, authors whose works in calculus of variations are older and haven't nor to do with it? (***)

(*) E.g., Goldstein, Marion/Thornton, Taylor, etc.

(**) A english translation in Todhunter, *History of the calculus of Variation*s, 1861. There's a recent text about this question: Goldstine, *A History of the Calculus of Variations from the 17th through the 19th Century*, 2011

(***) Euler, *Elementa calculi variationum*, 1766(there's english translation); Lagrange, *Méthode de maximis e minimis*, Miscellanea taurinensiea, T.I, 1759 (french translation in Ouvres de Lagrange, T.I); *Sur la methode des variations*, Miscellanea taurinensiea, t.IV, 1766(french translation in Ouvres de Lagrange, T.IV)

Comment: Would [hsm.se] be a better home for this question/

Comment: The site guidelines on history questions are [here](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8930/). This one seems to fall squarely on the [hsm.se] side of the divide.

Comment: I find this an interesting question. The physics community has gravitated to a particular way of demonstrating the Euler-Lagrange equation. I assume that when an author writes a new textbook most of the writing process is to reproduce the content of existing texbooks (either from memory or directly), updated where necessary. That is, I expect the uniformity isn't independent convergence, but reproduction.